# How to turn on OpenGL acceleration in QCustomPlot?

Tags: qt, qcustomplot

My Qt version is 5.12.2. I have added DEFINES += QCUSTOMPLOT_USE_OPENGL in my .pro file. My .pro file is shown below:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2019-04-05T21:23:52
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui
QT       += charts
QT       += network


greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets printsupport

TARGET = oscilloscope_msvc2015
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
DEFINES += QCUSTOMPLOT_USE_OPENGL


# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0
CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
    fourier.cpp \
    plotdata.cpp \
    datathread.cpp \
    axisthread.cpp \
    qcustomplot.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
    fourier.h \
    plotdata.h \
    datathread.h \
    axisthread.h \
    qcustomplot.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui \
    fourier.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

RESOURCES += \
    res.qrc
```

but when I use setOpenGl(true) to turn on OpenGL, it keeps reporting error:

```
void QCustomPlot::setOpenGl(bool, int) QCustomPlot can't use OpenGL because QCUSTOMPLOT_USE_OPENGL was not defined during compilation (add 'DEFINES += QCUSTOMPLOT_USE_OPENGL' to your qmake .pro file)
```

So how to turn on OpenGL acceleration in QCustomPlot?

Comment: You can show your .pro

Comment: I have added my .pro file. Please help me find out what's wrong.Thank you!

Comment: I have compiled an example of QCustomPlot with GCC in Linux and it does not generate any problem to me, maybe it is a problem of MSVC, it tries to delete the build folder and it recompiles.

Comment: Yes, I changed the compiler and there was no problem. Thank you!

Comment: post an answer..

Answer (score 1):

Try to run *qmake* and then *rebuild*.
I had this problem and after doing these, it was ok.